# How to show dropdown list using reportviewer

Tags: c#, .net, reportviewer

I want to develop an application which will keep records of different values based on time. Also it should show list of time stamp in first row, the values below time stamp will be changed as per selection on time stamp.

What I want to do is 
Flip the values based on select[image]ion of time stamp present in list.

Please refer attached image. values below need to be updated from database or array which I select time stamp from the drop down list.

Comment: what have you tried so far?

Comment: I got success to populate the report, but no success to show dropdown